# How do I convert all dataframe rows to a unique string in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe

**I have a dataFrame:**

```
V1,V2,V3,V4,V5
1.12331,4.331123,4.12335435,1,"asd"
1.123453345,5.654456,4.889999,1.45456,"qwe"
2.00098,5.5445,4.768799,1.999999,"ttre"
```

And I want to extract the first column, or all of columns if it's possible, to a string variable.

**I'm trying the code below:**

```
library(tidyverse)
td <- read_csv("test.csv")
```

Convert all the DataFrame to a String

```
var_text <- toString(td)
```

But the result is still not what I expect.

> [1] "c(1.12331, 1.123453345, 2.00098), c(4.331123, 5.654456, 5.5445), c(4.12335435, 4.889999, 4.768799), c(1, 1.45456, 1.999999)"

**I need something like:**

```
strResult = "1.12331, 1.123453345, 2.00098, 4.331123, 5.654456, 5.5445, 4.12335435, 4.889999, 4.768799, 1, 1.45456, 1.999999"
```

Answer (score 2):

`unlist` and then convert to string :

```
toString(unlist(df[-5]))
#[1] "1.12331, 1.123453345, 2.00098, 4.331123, 5.654456, 5.5445, 4.12335435, 4.889999, 4.768799, 1, 1.45456, 1.999999"
```

Or convert it to a matrix.

```
toString(as.matrix(df[-5]))
```

Here, I am excluding the last column since it is not included in the expected output.

Comment: toString(unlist(td[1:4]))  

and

toString(as.matrix(td[1:4]))


Both it works too! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(1.12331, 1.123453345, 2.00098), V2 = c(4.331123, 
5.654456, 5.5445), V3 = c(4.12335435, 4.889999, 4.768799), V4 = c(1, 
1.45456, 1.999999), V5 = c("asd", "qwe", "ttre")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")

#Code
#Create chain
df$chain <- apply(df,1,function(x) paste(x,collapse = ','))
#Now collapse all chain
paste(df$chain,collapse = ',')

[1] "1.123310,4.331123,4.123354,1.000000,asd,1.123453,5.654456,4.889999,1.454560,qwe,2.000980,5.544500,4.768799,1.999999,ttre"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to `paste` after `unlist`ing the data.frame.

```
paste(unlist(df[-5]), collapse = ", ")
#[1] "1.12331, 1.123453345, 2.00098, 4.331123, 5.654456, 5.5445, 4.12335435, 4.889999, 4.768799, 1, 1.45456, 1.999999"
```